# Facebook Creative works in Graph Explorer but not in application?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-ads-api

We're working on ad creation in our application, and I was wondering if anybody was experiencing what we're seeing. I can take write a URL to create a Link Ad in the Graph Explorer, and it will create it. If I paste that same URL into a test page on our application, it returns a Facebook Error Page saying something went wrong. Both the Explorer and our App our on Version 2.2.

This is the URL I'm using:

```
act_<replaced_with_id>/adcreatives?object_story_spec={"page_id":"707866599249399","link_data":{"link":"www.google.com","message":"Im an ad","caption":"Some awesome caption"}}
```

I've been trying to figure it out for a couple hours now, and making very little progress. I've made sure I'm admin of the Fan Page, tried with  and without images, not sure what else to do. I was also getting the same errors in the Ads API, so Im unsure what to try next.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the same access token in both cases?

Comment: Can you provide the full error message from FB when you run this from your app?

Comment: Please provide you response and we can take a look